# Xenial (16.04.1 LTS) goes back to sleep after opening laptop lid

Tags: 16.04, suspend, laptop, resume

I have a Razer Blade 2016 running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

I can close the lid and it suspends properly.  However, if I open the lid, the system will come back up but then go back to sleep after several seconds.  Additionally, the wireless network device is not available.  This will continue until the machine is rebooted.

However, if I use the `Shut down... -> Suspend` menu option or press the power button and select the Suspend option, I can then close and reopen the lid and everything behaves properly.

I found a [similar issue and solution on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/razer/comments/447vrn/razer_blade_stealth_linux/d4zfspx), but it involves installing `acpi-call-dkms` which requires disabling Secure Boot, and I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

My current workaround is setting `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and suspending the machine manually, but it's clunky and doesn't actually do what I want.

What's going on, and is there a real fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happens **sometimes* to me to where it wakes up, turns on built-in display and external TV for a moment and then goes back to sleep. Moving the mouse restores as if a normal resume.

I've had other issue of hibernating for 15 seconds when it was supposed to sleep in 2 seconds. I've even had issue of only the illusion of sleeping where screen turns off but fan was still spinning and power light was solid instead of halo. My first issue was when sleep only blanked out built-in display but external screen and all other programs (and sound) were still running.

In addition to the `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` setting in `logind.conf` you've made you can also try:

```
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no
```

"Docked" originally means laptop is attached to a docking station but it also means an external monitor is attached.

I must admit systemd design for `IgnoreInhibited` sounds like a double negative and it confuses me setting it to `no`.

The other option is to turn off Ubuntu handling of lid close in power settings with "Do nothing" and make systemd do it all.

The final extreme option (like I did) is write your own script for ACPI event/actions and tell Ubuntu and systemd to do nothing on lid close and lid open.

Anyway, if the suggestion works it's an answer, if it doesn't it's a long comment that won't fit where it belongs. I hope someone posts a definitive answer.